# How to show Product Item in Product List by array/object

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have to get all list of product from product Item that the place I display each product Item from Firebase, this is my code for that

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Button from '../Button/index';
import { DB } from '../../firebase/Firebase';
import "./index.css";


const ProductItem = ({ image, name, price }) => {
  var [productObjects, setProductObjects] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    DB.ref().child('products').on('value', (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.val() != null) {
        setProductObjects({
          ...snapshot.val(),
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="product-item">
      {Object.keys(productObjects).map((key) => (
        <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key={key}>
          <Card.Img variant="top" src={productObjects[key].image} />
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{productObjects[key].name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              {productObjects[key].price}
            </Card.Text>
            <Button
              onClick={() => { console.log("Add to card!") }}
              type="button"
              variant="success-outline"
              size="lg"
            >
              Add to card
            </Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      ))}
    </div>

  );
}

export default ProductItem;
```

And this is the place I want to show all list of product

```
import ProductItem from '../../components/ProductItem/index'

class ProductsPage extends Component {

const ProductItemList = [ProductItem]

const ShowProductItemList = ProductItemList.map((product, index) => {
    product.ProductItem
  })

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="products-container">
         {ShowProductItemList }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to show each product item in this page, but how can I do that

It was merged with all other items in an existing item.

[image]

That not right, I know, but I do not know how to do on this page. I want to display each item for this page. Can anyone help me, please! Thank for taking your time, thank you so much

You can check on this link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-chaplygin-n7kzj?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: get rid of `const ProductItemList` and `const ShowProductItemList`, and in render render product item directly `<div className="products-container"> <ProductItem/> </div>` also I guess you have some styling issue, try to make https://codesandbox.io so we can help better

Comment: Yes, I already edited my question

Comment: I checked the sandbox and does not show the way that you specified on the question, the problem might be on the `index.css` which should be in `ProductItem.js` as `import "./index.css";` but you did not put in the sandbox.